# Android Proguard, removing all Log statements and merging packages

Tags: android, proguard

1. I have about 5 packages in my project, is it possible to merge all the packages into one large package, I want to do this to make hacking more difficult.
2. How do I remove all references to Log.e Log.d etc. in my source code using proguard. (I have the eclipse ADT with proguard integrated already).

Update: Looks like part 2 can be done like this

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The option -repackageclasses moves obfuscated classes into a single given package:

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#repackageclasses

You can optionally combine it with -allowaccessmodification for better results.