# Is it neccessary to remove Log and Debugging before app release?

Tags: android

In the Android docs it talks about getting an application ready for the market.

It says that you should deactivite Log and debugging.

Is this totally neccessary? Or just an suggestion?

Also how do you go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove all logging by running progruard with the correct options.

[Android Proguard, removing all Log statements and merging packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435773/android-proguard-removing-all-log-statements-and-merging-packages)

Has some of the options needed. Takes some understanding of Proguard but allows the source to keep the log messages while not worrying about them in a released application. Additionally, you can add the other methods to the config as well to remove logging completely. Not all applications do this. Many of Google's own applications are fairly chatty on the log in release.

Comment: just what I was looking for.. 10q