# What am i doing wrong in ProGuard configuration to remove log lines?

Tags: android, proguard

I am trying to remove logging lines from my apk and i use proguard for this.

It doesn't remove the lines, what can be the problem? (i know that proguard is on, because i test the apk by decompiling to see if it is obfuscated)

This is the full contents of my proguard config file:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only remove logging if optimization is not disabled, which requires specifying a different global configuration file in `project.properties`:

```
  proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Similar questions and answers:

- [Removing Log call using proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218772/removing-log-call-using-proguard)
- [Removing unused strings during ProGuard optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009078/removing-unused-strings-during-proguard-optimisation)
- [Removing logging with ProGuard doesn't remove the strings being logged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086920/removing-logging-with-proguard-doesnt-remove-the-strings-being-logged)
- [How to config my proguard-project.txt file to remove just Logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123866/how-to-config-my-proguard-project-txt-file-to-remove-just-logs)
- [Android Proguard Options - Stricter Rules & Remove Log Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790549/android-proguard-options-stricter-rules-remove-log-statements)