# Android Logging - Debug Logs stripped at runtime

Tags: android, logging

Android documentation says:  Debug logs are compiled in but stripped at runtime

I have read through a lot of Q&A on stack overflow and other forums related to this and directions on how to get around by using custom logging class with conditions on logging level depending on whether the app is in debug stage or release state. And also the use of ProGaurd to help with it.

I am still not clear with the documentation.

"Debug logs are compiled in but stripped at runtime" -- Does this means android logger or some other component in the framework takes care of it OR We are supposed to ensure that debug logs are compiled in but stripped at runtime?

Comment: Any comments or Ideas

Comment: possible duplicate of [are Android's debug logs really stripped at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238450/are-androids-debug-logs-really-stripped-at-runtime)